# Remove doubles before export

Tags: unity

I use blender along with Unity. My .blend file sits in unity project directory and each time I make a change to the .blend file, unity refrshes the scene and loads that file.

I would love to have a option to call *remove doubles* just before that .blend file is read by unity. I know modifiers are aplied during that unity export/read, but i could not find appropriate modifier for that task.

Is there a way to call *remove doubles* by a script or something like that, before each time unity exports/reads that .blend file ?

Comment: Selecting the entire mesh. hitting "Space" and typing "remove doubles" does not do the trick for you?

Comment: I would love to remove the doubles just before export and unity triggers the export by itsleft so i cant control that.

Comment: Unity triggers the export? No, it shouldn't be at least.

Comment: I mean i have .blend file and unity in my unity project and each time i make a change unity refreshes itselft and exports/reads the blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this script will remove doubles on the currently selected mesh and export the file with a filename appended with `-unity`

You can then set unity to read the `-unity` blend and run the script instead of `save`.

```
import bpy
newfilename = bpy.context.blend_data.filepath.replace(".blend","-unity.blend")
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(copy=True, filepath=newfilename)
```